# How to make output video mosaic with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code

```
def myimage(img):
    img2 = dosomething(img) #just example
    output_image = np.zeros(((img.shape[0] + data.mymap.shape[0]), img.shape[1]*2, 3))
    output_image[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]] = img
    output_image[0:img.shape[0], img.shape[1]:] = img2
```

I have a function that call  image(myimage) and build a video (video is a sequence of images), with moviepy and works fine.

My question is, How to make a mosaic with more images ? How to add more  **output_image** to compile everything to make one movie only ? I tried differents ways but do not work, I always find an error.